Failed to resume your working changes from the cloud
I get the error "Failed to resume your working changes from the cloud." when I launch my application on Vs code. The github source control is also empty, it just shows the blue loading icon and after the icon disappears I get the error. The source control does not track the new changes in the app and some codes are missing. The files are there but there is no code.
However, when I check the file in my finders the codes are there.
